# unable to compile class for jsp with root cause string index out of range

Tags: java, jsp

i have been facing this error whenever i try to run the code. what i do here is the jsp page is redirected from a filter using the following code:

```
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/myPage.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

the browser displays the Error

`Unable to compile class for jsp" along with the root cause "String index out of range: 0`

the myPage.jsp page is as follows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %> 
<%@ page session="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>My page</title>


</head>

<body>
    <p>My text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace ? i guess it is something wrong with the filters you are trying

Comment: i didn't add any function in the homecontroller for this page. is it mandatory when redirecting from requestdispatcher???....um kinda new in this.